# xmllint not operator in the predicate not working

Tags: xml-parsing, xmllint

my requirement is to get alias of ancestor who attribute is not equal to A

```
<Instance>
  <Context>
   <InstanceDescription alias="A">
     <AttributDescription attrid="A"/>
      </AttributDescription>
   </InstanceDescription>
   <InstanceDescription alias="B">
   <Context>
       <AttributDescription attrid="b">
      </AttributDescription>
   ..
   ..

 </InstanceDescription>
</Instance>
```

I tried with the following command , however it gives me syntax error .

```
myval="cat //Instance/InstanceDescription/Context/AttributDescription[not(@attrId = \"'A'\")]/ancestor::InstanceDescription/@alias  | xmllint --shell $filename"
```

also tried not(@attrId = 'A'). still the same.

Comment: What is the syntax error? Does your version of xmllint not support `--xpath`? What should be the output of xmllint; `B` or `alias="B"`?

Comment: using --xpath with xmllint give me command not found. am expecting the B as the output. however for outputting alias="B" or B , can always format it.that not the issue. problem is i need use a not operator in the predicate